# Object turns white

Tags: unity, animation, materials

Any idea why this character turns white in Game window with Play button on and off? The character is fine when the animations are not present but the file with the animations shows the character as white and the animation doesn't start even though the animator animation bar looks as though the animation should be running.

[image]

I've uploaded the character file at the link below, basically if this character is dragged in a new project the Game tab will show it as all white.

https://easyupload.io/5xzvm7

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: every step we need to follow to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project, given that we do not have your model to test with. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential solutions to be sure you get a fix that works for your case.

Comment: i added a comment with a link to the character. Is this enough to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FBX file has a pile of point lights in it. These bathe the model in bright light from all sides, over-exposing it until it shines pure white.

Right-click on your prefab instance in the scene and select "Prefab->Unpack", then select the seven child objects named "Point" through "Point.006" and delete them.

Now you can rename the root "Xenomorph-noLights", and drag it into your Project window to create a new prefab with all the mesh and animation information, but without the unwanted lights.